# MongoDB mapReduce() query to aggregate data into a list inside a record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with records of the form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562d6d9c3a2e9c0adbb02f14"),
    "slug" : "1:955553",
    "subslug" : "1:955553:02",
    "score" : "0.615",
    "position_start" : "1",
    "position_end" : 955553,
    "name" : "AGRN",
    "ref" : "A"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562d6d9c3a2e9c0adbb02f15"),
    "slug" : "2:15553",
    "subslug" : "2:15553:01",
    "score" : "0.915",
    "position_start" : "1002",
    "position_end" : 15553,
    "name" : "MMFR",
    "ref" : "C"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562d6d9c3a2e9c0adbb02f16"),
    "slug" : "1:955553",
    "subslug" : "1:955553:01",
    "score" : "0.715",
    "position_start" : 1,
    "position_end" : 955553,
    "name" : "AGRN",
    "ref" : "A"
},
```

I would like to aggregate this collection and group by slug (notice the first and third records here have the same slug).

I am trying to aggregate my data into a new collection that looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "<?>",
    "slug" : "1:955553",
    "components" : [ 
       { 
         "subslug": "1:955553:01",
         "score": 0.615,
         "position_start": 1,
         "position_end": 955553,
         "name": AGRN,
         "ref": "A"
       },
       { 
         "subslug": "1:955553:02",
         "score": 0.715,
         "position_start": 1,
         "position_end": 955553,
         "name": AGRN,
         "ref": "A"
       },

    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "<?>",
    "slug" : "2:15553",
    "components" : [ 
       { 
         "subslug": "2:15553:01",
         "score": 0.915,
         "position_start": 1002,
         "position_end": 15553,
         "name": MMFR,
         "ref": "C"
       }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use *mapReduce()* to accomplish this, but I am having some difficulties working out the details of the functions.

I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('vest').mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.slug, { 'components': {$push: this } });
    },
    function(key, components) {
        return components[0];
    },
    {
        out: 'mytable'
    }
)
```

Yet this unfortunately builds a table that looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "1:955553",
    "value" : {
        "components" : {
            "$push" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("562d6d9c3a2e9c0adbb02f14"),
                "slug" : "1:955553",
                "subslug" : "1:955553:01",
                "position_start" : 1,
                "position_end" : 955553,
                "gene" : "AGRN",
                "ref" : "A"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is not what I need. I was trying to use `$push` to append a `components` array, but clearly `$push` is not respected in `mapReduce()`.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to take the input collection data above and create the desired output collection? Am I on the right track with my `mapReduce()` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use the **[`aggregation framework`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** for such operation which should be multiple times faster than the map-reduce operation.

Typically you would construct an aggregation pipeline that consists of 3 stages:

- **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage - This pipeline step groups the documents by the `slug` field as its key, then apply the accumulator operator **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** to create the `components` array that is a result of applying an expression to each document in the above group.
- **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage - This will reshape each document in the stream, such as by adding new fields or removing existing fields.
- **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** stage - This final step will writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to a new collection.

So, using the above operation, running the following aggregation pipeline will give you the desired result in a new collection called `mytable`:

```
db.vest.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$slug",
            "components": {
                "$push": {
                    "subslug": "$subslug",
                     "score": "$score",
                     "position_start": "$position_start",
                     "position_end": "$position_end",
                     "name": "$name",
                     "ref": "$ref"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "slug": "$_id", "components": 1
        }
    },
    { "$out": "mytable" }
])
```

Querying this collection with the above sample data

```
db.mytable.find()
```

will give you the desired output:

**Sample Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("563bc608d1f71f49c3d6c80b"),
    "components" : [ 
        {
            "subslug" : "2:15553:01",
            "score" : "0.915",
            "position_start" : "1002",
            "position_end" : 15553,
            "name" : "MMFR",
            "ref" : "C"
        }
    ],
    "slug" : "2:15553"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("563bc608d1f71f49c3d6c80c"),
    "components" : [ 
        {
            "subslug" : "1:955553:02",
            "score" : "0.615",
            "position_start" : "1",
            "position_end" : 955553,
            "name" : "AGRN",
            "ref" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "subslug" : "1:955553:01",
            "score" : "0.715",
            "position_start" : 1,
            "position_end" : 955553,
            "name" : "AGRN",
            "ref" : "A"
        }
    ],
    "slug" : "1:955553"
}
```

Comment: This looks really great. My collection is large, so I'm running into memory limits. I have tried adding: `...], { allowDiskUse : true }` but I'm still seeing the same `Exceeded memory limit for $group` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: When I add the `$match` element to pre-filter the query, this works excellent!

Comment: Another update (for those in the future): The error I saw was actually due having a client pre 2.6. I upgraded my mongo client and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't and should use mapReduce for this. You should instead you the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/). All you need is [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents by "slug" and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator to return an array of all other fields. The [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage is used to exclude the `_id' field from your aggregation result.

That being said you can use the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) operator  the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to another collection as mentioned in @chridam's answer but because

> You cannot specify a sharded collection as the output collection. The input collection for a pipeline can be sharded.
>
> The $out operator cannot write results to a [capped collection.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/)

You should use ["Bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations to write you result to a new collections.

```js
var bulk = db.newcollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$slug", 
        "components": {
            "$push": {
                "subslug": "$subslug",
                "score": "$score", 
                "position_start": "$position_start", 
                "position_end": "$position_end",
                "name": "$name", 
                "ref": "$ref"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": { 
        "slug": "$_id",
        "components": 1, 
        "_id": 0
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
        bulk.insert(doc);
})

bulk.execute();
```

Then `db.newcollection.find()` yields something like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("563bc8a6bf93306f8f6638ce"),
        "components" : [
                {
                        "slug" : "1:955553",
                        "subslug" : "1:955553:02",
                        "score" : "0.615",
                        "position_start" : "1",
                        "position_end" : 955553,
                        "name" : "AGRN",
                        "ref" : "A"
                },
                {
                        "slug" : "1:955553",
                        "subslug" : "1:955553:01",
                        "score" : "0.715",
                        "position_start" : 1,
                        "position_end" : 955553,
                        "name" : "AGRN",
                        "ref" : "A"
                }
        ],
        "slug" : "1:955553"
}
```